# What medium should be kept beneath the paper for papercutting?

Tags: tool-selection, papercutting

Natural conclusion that we can draw from [this question about cutting small circles](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/13/how-to-cut-a-tiny-circle-in-paper) is that it is obvious the cutting tool or implement would need to be very sharp to be effective.

I used to use cemented floor for placing the paper for such papercutting when I was a child.

Since the tools would be that sharp they are going to affect the working surface below the paper. Another concern would be the paper moving around on that working medium.

Considering the above factors, what medium should be kept *beneath* the paper when papercutting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Self healing cutting mat

[image]

I use this for all my craft cutting. You want to be sure that the surface you are cutting on is completely uniform so as to not cause your cutting hand to hesitate or jump. These mats are for just that.

Also has the added feature of not cutting up your parent's table. They are usually textured on both side to prevent both the mat and the work from moving around. This also allows the mat to be flipped over and use the other side thus extending the life of the mat. It will eventually wear out though.

---

You can usually find these in a variety of sizes to suit your need. Some companies make ones small enough that you can keep in a book if you travel.

There appears to be, or at least used to be, a small mystery about what these mats are actually made of. [One manufacturer describes it as:](http://www.cutting-mats.net/self-healing-cutting-mats.html)

> unique composite PVC vinyl material

Comment: Thanks, you said it is textured.  I want to know will it be practical to cut thin paper on it?

Comment: Define thin? I use this for _all_ my paper cutting from computer paper to cardstock. Standard computer paper is about 0.1 mm thick. Textured might have been the wrong word. Rubbery feel?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius I still use my opposite hand to steady the work if that is what you mean.